# How can I create a Blog Module using Microsoft Webmatrix?

Tags: webmatrix

If I am creating a ASP.NET Website, how i can add blogging module using webmatrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to add blogging to an ASP.NET site with WebMatrix is to use one of the applications in the app gallery.  I suggest taking a look at Umbraco:

http://umbraco.com/

Here are some links for help getting started:

- http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/installing-umbraco-with-webmatrix
- http://umbraco.com/help-and-support/video-tutorials/getting-started/working-with-webmatrix.aspx

You can also take a look at Orchard, another CMS written in .NET:

http://orchardproject.net/

Happy coding!